# Convert binary String to hexadecimal String

Tags: vb.net, kotlin, binary, hex

I have this conversion in my Kotlin class for Android:

```
val binary = "01000100000111001011011011100010111000110011010111010110"
val hexadecimal = BigInteger(binary, 2).toString(16)
```

Which is producing the expected value of **`441CB6E2E335D6`**.

Now I want to reproduce this in Visual Basic and I am doing something like this:

```
Dim binary = "01000100000111001011011011100010111000110011010111010110"
Dim hexadecimal = BigInteger.Parse(binary, 2).ToString("X")
```

Which is producing **`0A7108304A751AFEC876F740BC1F2CB59772FB7C6C753E`**.

I am not an expert in Visual Basic, but from what I researched, I think this is the right way to convert a binary to hexadecimal. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a note: the second parameter in `Parse` is not the base, but the enum `NumberStyles` where 2 is `AllowTrailingWhite`. You are simply parsing it as a decimal.

Comment: @ZorgoZ alright. So doing only BigInteger.Parse(binary) should do the work, right?

Comment: No. Have you seen anywhere in the documentation, that it can parse binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple parser for the string representing the bits:

```
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
For pos As Integer = 0 To binary.Length - 8 Step 8
    sb.Append(Convert.ToByte(binary.Substring(pos, 8), 2).ToString("X2"))
Next
```

```
Console.WriteLine(sb) will print "441CB6E2E335D6"
```

Or use a Module to add an extension method to the string data type:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Text

Module modStringExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToHexFromBits(ByVal Value As String) As String
        If (Not (Value.Length Mod 8 = 0)) Then Throw New FormatException("Invalid string length")
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        For pos As Integer = 0 To Value.Length - 8 Step 8
            sb.Append(Convert.ToByte(Value.Substring(pos, 8), 2).ToString("X2"))
        Next
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
End Module
```

Then use the extension to convert the bits string to a *HEX* representation:

```
Dim result As String = binary.ToHexFromBits()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is c#, but might not be too hard to translate it to vb.net.

```
string BinToHex(string value)
{
    var res = new char[(int)(value.Length / 4)];
    int j = res.Length-1;
    for (int i = value.Length - 1; i > 0; i -= 4)
    {
        int x =  ((int)value[i]-48) 
                +((int)value[i-1]-48)*2
                +((int)value[i-2]-48)*4
                +((int)value[i-3]-48)*8;

        res[j--] = x.ToString("X")[0];
    }

    return new string(res);
}
```

Beware: it won't handle input that has not the proper number of bits (multiple of 4). Anyway, the idea is that you can translate between base 2 and base 16 without the use of base 10. You could even step from left to right.